# python class decorator error

Tags: python

In the below when applying the decorator i get an error as `TypeError: rt() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` ,how to get over this. the same goes with  function decorator also ,hIs it because of the parent class.How to resolve this.

```
class applyfilter(object):
    def __init__(self,f):
       self.f=f
    def __call__(self,*args):
       self.f(*args)
```

or

```
def applyfilter(f):
    def rt1(*args):
        print f.__name__
        print args
        return f(*args)
    return rt1

 class T1(SuperClass):
     @applyfilter
     def rt(self,data):
        print "In function rt" 

t=T1()
t.rt(123)

TypeError: rt() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: You're not passing any `data` to `rt()`.

Comment: Corrected it in the question

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `*` operator in your function call, like so:

```
def rt1(*args):
    print f.__name__
    print args
    return f(*args)
```

This way, the parameters to `rt1` will be packed into `args`, and then unpacked in the call to `f(*args)`.

Reference: [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Your correction is still missing the the asterisk on `def rt1(*args)`.